# In Julia 1.0+ convert a floating-point number to a string retaining the original format

Tags: julia

I would like to convert a floating point number to a string, retaining the original format of the digits.  Here are some ideas I have tried:

```
julia> VERSION
v"1.0.3"
```

#### Notice the format with 9 digits before decimal point:

```
julia> x = 123456789.123;
```

#### These two attempts changed the format:

```
julia> string(x)  
"1.23456789123e8"

julia> repr(x)
"1.23456789123e8"
```

Here is what I would like:

```
julia> to_string(x)
## 123456789.123
```

This seems simple, but I have not found a way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `using Printf ; x = 123456789.123 ; @printf("%9.3f", x)`... unless I've misunderstood the question...

Comment: @printf requires you to hardcode the 9 and the 3.  However, there may be a way to use your suggestion.  I was hoping for a general solution for any floating point number. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl?

Comment: I have checked it in the past, but not recently.  In general, I think it is hard to know how many digits to the right of the decimal point were originally given.  It is possible to use @sprintf to hardcode a number or one of the options in Formatting to dynamically specify a number of digits.  But how does one know the number of digits originally given when the variable was initialized?

Comment: What does "original" mean? If it means the literal string in your source code, I would say it's impossible (unless you use some black magic to read the source code again and find the original string). For example, if such a `to_string` exists, what does it even mean in `to_string(123.3456 + 0.1)`? such a result never have an "original" representation, or should it show "123.3456 + 0.1"?

Comment: By "original" I meant the number that initialized a variable.

Comment: What you want is definitely impossible if all you are doing is writing `x = 123.456`. The number is just a `Float64`. No formatting information is being stored. You would need to build a custom struct to store both the `Float64` and formatting information at the point of initialization if you really wanted this. And inferring the formatting information based on how the number is typed in your code sounds extremely non-trivial to me (at the least, I think it will require some sort of macro/metaprogramming magic - I don't want to say impossible :-)

Comment: Yes, after asking the question and reading the comments, I realized I was up against the limitations of floating point arithmetic.  The digits after the decimal point may not even exist, precisely, after the initial number is converted to a `Float64`.  However, that is an interesting idea of a custom struct.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's not just about the limitations of floating point. There is just no way to distinguish between e.g. `1.0` and `1.00`, or between `4/2` and `2.0`, after they have been parsed and turned into a number. I cannot imagine how any number system could (or should!) distinguish between the two.

Comment: @DNF Yes, good point.  I have not had any experience with it, but I wonder if a binary coded digits system could tell the difference between 1.0 and 1.00?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If it could tell the difference, that would be a _bad_ thing, surely?

Comment: @DNF Maybe there would be a use case for 1.0 indicating 2 sig digits and 1.00 indicating 3 sig digits of measurement precision?  Again, I have never used binary coded decimal, (BCD), so I don't know all the use cases BCD addresses.

Comment: @DNF I did a little searching for a BCD converter.  The one at: https://planetcalc.com/1674/ produces a different number for these two decimal inputs.  23.8 goes to Binary Coded Decimal 0010 0011.1000 and 23.80 goes to a different BCD 0010 0011.1000 0000
Not all the BCD converters work with fractions, but this one did.

Comment: So there _is_ one. Ok, but it doesn't seem like a good idea. As the authors says: "But it wasn't widely adopted, cause it makes life more difficult... for computers."